# add multi-domain users to sharepoint from azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad

I have two domains say domain1 (default) and domain2 in azure AD.

when i migrate the users from both domains to a SharePoint site they get migrated successfully but when I login with the user from domain2 it automatically takes domain1 as the user domain.

example : login with domain2\xysUser automatically changes to domain1\xyzUser when clicked on Ok and the login gets failed everytime.

generally in local windows we can overcome this by establishing a two-way trust between the domains, but I can not find any such way in azure AD.

Can any provide me with a solution by which I can login with multiple domains to a SharePoint in an Azure VM